# How to allow screensaver while fullscreen app is active

Tags: windows-10, screensaver, fullscreen

Wondering how do I allow a timed screensaver to activate while a fullscreen app is active. For example, a YouTube video is playing fullscreen which normally would prevent the screensaver from activating. How do I get the screensaver to remain active?

Running Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Remain active while a YouTube is playing the background. You likely won't be able to do that if the tab within the browser is active (i.e. not suspended).

Comment: not sure what I did, but now my screensaver wont work at all =(

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by the program. Programs call SetThreadExecutionState to tell windows not to sleep or turn monitor off while playing video then calls it when the video ends to go back to normal. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate.

So you'll find the setting, if a program has one, in the program's settings. EG in Windows Media Player Options it's *Allow Screensaver During Playback*.